# Why is the beam bending stiffness taken as $EI/L$?

Tags: structural-engineering

In moment distribution method, the bending stiffness of a beam is taken as $EI/L$. But in these kinds of stiffness tables, the flexural rigidity is usually divided by some power of $L$:
[image]

So why is $EI$ divided by simply $L$ to get the bending stiffness, instead of some of its powers as in the tables? Could somebody provide a quick derivation? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"**Stiffness**" quantifies the level of resistance of a structural member against **deformation** under loads. Two types of deformations are of particular concern - **translation and rotation**, in structural engineering.

- **Translation deformation**: The stiffness is the invert of the member flexibility ($f$), which is an index of member deflection ($\Delta$), so $K = \frac{1}{f} = \frac{1}{\Delta}$. For member subjects to uniform load, $\Delta = \frac {5wL^4}{384EI}$, $K = \frac {384EI}{5wL^4}$; for member subjects to mid-span concentrate load, $\Delta = \frac{PL^3}{48EI}$, $K = \frac{48EI}{PL^3}$, and so on for other load cases. $K$ is sometimes referred to as the member "**deflection/deformation stiffness**".
- **Rotational deformation**: The stiffness is the invert of the flexibility of the member end rotation when subjects to the applied moment. The flexibility is the index of rotation $f = \theta = \int \frac {M}{EI} dx$, and $K = \frac{M}{\theta} = \frac{EI}{L}$. This is the stiffness used in the moment distribution method, and in the structural stiffness matrix of the finite element program. It is sometimes referred to as the "**bending stiffness**".

One special case, for member subjects to uniaxial loads (tension/compression) only, such as the truss member, $K = \frac{EA}{L}$.

Answer (score 0):

I/L is relative stiffness.  For the same flexural member material and cross sectional characteristics, the longer the flexural member, the more it displaces/deflects.   Therefore, I/L provides a relative stiffness value depending on member's length.